# YouTube player doesn't show video information in playlist

Tags: c#, javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

I'm working on a web tool (just for personal use as of now) that grabs *n* of the most recent youtube videos posted to a blog and creates an "ad hoc" playlist. I am using the iFrame API for the embedded player. Everything is working, I'm just curious about a few *quirks*

When the player loads the playlist and begins playing, the player enables the "playlist" button in the toolbar. I can click that and see thumbnails for all, let's say 10, videos. But for some reason, the video info isn't populated. Next to each thumbnail I only see the text "by" (see below)

[image: Screenshot]

Originally I used `player.cuePlaylist`, and when I switched to `player.loadPlaylist` it actually loaded all of the information correctly - once. Running it a second time with no code changes, it came out the same way again, with no data.

Has anyone else run into this? I'm loading the playlist with a `videoID` Array if that helps. The js looks like this:

```
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.loadPlaylist([ <%= videoIds %> ]);
    event.target.playVideo();
}
```

And checking the page's source, the array (videoIds) is compiled correctly. Something like this:

```
['mxb7998a','BBao088','12345pp','8Aeo00']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug. You can star and track it here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5082